# Kotlin: How to call suspendable function without awaiting its result?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, asynchronous, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I want to trigger a function called `initiateFulFillment` inside the function `confirmPayment`, but I do not want to wait inside `confirmPayment` until the execution of `initiateFulFillment` is finished. This is because the result of `confirmPayment` does not depend on the call of `initiateFulFillment`.

It seems to be working when I use `GlobalScope.launch` to trigger `initiateFulFillment`, but I wonder if this is a good way of achieving what I want or whether there is some better way?

Because in my IDE I get a warning that `GloablScope` is a delicate API and it only should be used, when it has to be used.

```
fun confirmPayment(orderId: Int): Boolean {
    // * some validation *
    GlobalScope.launch {
        initiateFulFillment(orderId)
    }
    return true
}

suspend fun initiateFulFillment(orderId: Int) {
    // * initiating fulfillment *
}
```

Comment: Generally, the warning says such "fire and forget" background operations are bad for application reliability. We don't track the background operation, we don't know if it succeeded and react to its failures, we can't cancel it if it is not needed anymore, etc. It is recommended every background task has its owner and the owner in the coroutines world means its context/scope (actually, `Job`). Proper solution is to create a `CoroutineScope` and manage its lifecycle, then use it for `async()`.

Comment: @broot thank you very much, this is really helpful! Creating a custom scope makes definetely sense. But why do you recommend using `async` when I am not expecting any result, shouldn't I use `launch` here?

Comment: Ahh, good point, yes, `launch()` is enough :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `GlobalScope` is typically used to perform application-lifetime work, you indeed should not use it for short or limited tasks, that are view/activity/fragment specific.

Using scope for this is fine, so you need to create a custom one for that. There are a lot of ways to create and setup a custom coroutine scope, I will show the most simple one.

```
val customScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())

...

fun confirmPayment(orderId: Int): Boolean {
    // * some validation *
    customScope.launch {
        initiateFulFillment(orderId)
    }
    return true
}
```

UPD: You should note, that if this code runs in some kind of a view model, and the user leaves the screen, scope can be cleared and thus it will not wait for work to finish.

UPD2: I use IO dispatcher in my example, it is suitable for network calls. However, if this is a some kind of computation and is not related to sending requests and waiting for responses, you should probably use `Dispatchers.Default`